# databasename.d.first_column_in_the_table' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, eclipse, birt

i always get the same error whenever i run this query.
i tried using simple query to test if there is something wrong in the query.
I also noticed that error happened when im using the view in my query.

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_vss_car_wash AS

```
     SELECT
     max(r.id) AS id
    ,d.id AS dealer_id
    ,d.dealer_code
    ,d.dealer_name
    ,count(*) AS total_respondents
    ,sum(car_washed) AS car_washed                  -- Car Washed
    ,count(*) - sum(car_washed) AS car_unwashed     -- Car Unwashed
    ,sum(IF (car_washed AND car_satisfied, 1, 0)) AS car_satisfied
    ,sum(IF (car_washed AND NOT car_satisfied, 1, 0)) AS car_unsatisfied
    ,MONTH(r.create_date) AS create_month
    ,YEAR(r.create_date) AS create_year
FROM t_vss_survey_response r 
    LEFT JOIN t_vss_dealer d ON (r.dealer_id = d.id)
WHERE survey_code = "ASS"
GROUP BY dealer_code, YEAR(r.create_date), MONTH(r.create_date);
```

then this is my query im using(very simple) but i always get the same error.

select a.dealer_name, a.dealer_code
from v_vss_car_wash a

now, this is the error message

Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot get the result set metadata.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: **SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
SQL error #1:'crmsdbdev.d.dealer_name' isn't in GROUP BY**
 ;
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 'crmsdbdev.d.dealer_name' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: simply add `d.dealer_name` in the *GROUP BY* clause. `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` might be turned on that's why you need to add all columns in the *SELECT* clause that are not aggregated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the appropriate columns to the `group by`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_vss_car_wash AS
SELECT
     max(r.id) AS id
    ,d.id AS dealer_id
    ,d.dealer_code
    ,d.dealer_name
    ,count(*) AS total_respondents
    ,sum(car_washed) AS car_washed                  -- Car Washed
    ,count(*) - sum(car_washed) AS car_unwashed     -- Car Unwashed
    ,sum(IF (car_washed AND car_satisfied, 1, 0)) AS car_satisfied
    ,sum(IF (car_washed AND NOT car_satisfied, 1, 0)) AS car_unsatisfied
    ,MONTH(r.create_date) AS create_month
    ,YEAR(r.create_date) AS create_year
FROM t_vss_survey_response r 
    LEFT JOIN t_vss_dealer d ON (r.dealer_id = d.id)
WHERE survey_code = "ASS"
GROUP BY d.id, d.dealer_code, d.dealer_name,
         YEAR(r.create_date), MONTH(r.create_date);
```